# joomla 3 refresh cache using cronjob

Tags: php, caching, curl, joomla, joomla3.0

Please anybody with sufficient technical experience could please verify or suggest an alternate on how to achieve the following:

I am using a specific component for CCK in a Joomla 3 installation. Unfortunately all its listing pages are quite slow since heavy customization has been made. I have activated caching for this specific component in order to speed up specific pages of my website. Cache interval is 2 hours.

I would like to find a way to force refresh cache every 2h 01mins so as to minimize slow page load user experience.

so I am thinking to create a php script which will manually access (http request) these pages! then I am thinking of executing this script using a cronjob (server side) every 2h 01mins to re-create the cached version of these pages.

so my question is simply the following:

a) Could a php script "load" somehow these pages (by URL)? Could I use something like php `cURL`? If not could you suggest any other options for "loading" these pages using a script on server side?

Answer (score 1):

Based on your use case, you could use a simple cURL script to load the page in question.  This would force Joomla to re-render and cache.

```
<?php
 $ch = curl_init();
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.website.com/my-cached-path");
 $contents = curl_exec ($ch);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
 curl_close ($ch);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

This script will clear cache, you can put it in a cron job.

```
https://github.com/elinw/jshell/blob/master/clearcache.php
```

Comment: no! i do not want to clear cache. I would like to force recreate it just for some pages! So i need a script that will access somehow specific URLs and it will recreate the cache!

Comment: Oh got it (not enough coffee yet), ok I think in that case you could still run a cli butusing other parts of the JCache API i.e. make a JCache object and then store().  You need to work through the steps to generate the data to store.

Comment: Thanks Elin. So you mean somethinhg like initializing the cache using JCache API. I will take a look at it...

Comment: Seems that this scipt is only working in Joomla 2 and not in Joomla 3.